# Is it possible to show digital texts in TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview

Hi friends,

In my application there is a requirement that the text values should be shown in a **digital text** format can it be possible to do in **TextView** (How digital clock shows)? Any help please.

Comment: download the digital font and set to your text view http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,24267,digital-7.html

Comment: Hello Padma Kumar It seems like a textual file right? How can I make it available to my application. Any folder need to be created in the res folder. Please help. And

Answer (score 20, accepted):

//download the font from the this [link](http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,24267,digital-7.html) and create a folder as fonts inside your assets and put your font in that folder

or download direct [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?x23ure8duruv4ga)

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/digital_07.otf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalclock);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

**EDIT :**

I attached the project [link also](http://www.mediafire.com/?eza7hxy1bxmbk93)

Enjoy :-)

Comment: hi Padma, Please how can I make all textual file which I downloaded from [here](http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,24267,digital-7.html) available to my application? Thanks for all your valuable time to help me

Comment: @user11851 click the download image @ bottm http://font.downloadatoz.com/download,24267,digital-7-font-for-linux.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me check it out

Comment: Hello that all are digital text files how these can be put in the fonts folder.I couldn't get How do you do can you elaborate a little bit more please.

Comment: Yes now it works fine boss. Thanks a lot for your information. Chala Bagaundi!

Comment: Project and font not found on the mentioned link :(

Comment: You can find similar fonts [here](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital+clock-fonts.html)