# Android Application in Gujarati font

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am developing application which is having Gujarati font in text-view but my problem is that in text-view it shows the box instead of Gujarati font  i have tried by "TypeFace" and text is at string.xml but it is not working please help me i have to submit on tuesday at school so please please help me

Thank you in advance

`TextView cap = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.caption); 
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/gujaratifont.ttf"); 
cap.setTypeface(tf);
cap.setText(R.string.gujarati);`

Comment: where you have place the font in your project

Comment: in asset/fonts/gujaratifont.ttf

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9276715/1012284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop your file in assets Folder.

Try to do like this. `getResources().getString(R.string.gujarati);`

Its one reason is  because Resources could not get to the TextView. Just Check it out.

Comment: @jssalat : Try this thing ==> final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Saumil_guj2.ttf"); 
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
        tv.setText("Hello HOw are you");

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView cap = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.caption);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/gujaratifont.ttf");
//(or)
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"gujaratifont.ttf");
cap.setTypeface(tf);
cap.setText(R.string.gujarati);
```

and place your font file in assets folder.
i.e., create a folder with name fonts in assets folder and place that gujarati font in fonts folder.

if you want gujarati font download it from [HERE](http://www.suratmunicipal.org/content/downloads/gujfonts/main.shtml)

Comment: no all is ok but still not working can i mail you my project?

Comment: than how can i do this?? please help me to do this besause i have to submit my project on tuesday

Comment: I have checked on all the devices

Answer (score 0):

TextView mtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

```
       Typeface face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 

                 "Lohit-Gujarati.ttf"); 

       mtxt.setTypeface(face1); 

       mtxt.setText("પૂર્વ વડાપ્રધાન રાજીવ ગાંધી");
```